# Show that a certain length is maximized when lines are parallel

Tags: geometry, optimization, euclidean-geometry

Consider two fixed circles whose interiors are not disjoint with centers $A$ and $B$. Let a line $\ell$ be drawn perpendicular to line $AB$, which intersects both circles at $X$ and $Y$ respectively. The question is how to place $\ell$ to to maximize the length of $XY$. (Note that line $\ell$ intersects each circle twice; since we want to maximize $XY$ we choose $X$ and $Y$ so that they are on opposite sides of $AB$).

My conjecture is that we should place $\ell$ so that $AX$ and $BY$ are parallel but I am unsure of how to prove this.

Ideally I would have a geometric proof because the original statement is geometrical, and often, these optimization problems have a nice way of looking at them that makes it obvious where the maximal case occurs.

[image]

Comment: Your conjecture seems plausible. Consider tangent lines on each circle, one at $X$ and one at $Y$. They too will be parallel. This means if $\ell$ moves up, $X$ moves to the right slower than $Y$ so the line gets shorter. Likewise, if $\ell$ moves down, $X$ moves to the left faster than $Y$ and again, the segment gets shorts. This seems like a line of attack for a proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would really just compute it analytically, and say the derivative is equal to $0$. I use $BY=b$, $AX=a$, $DB=x$. Then you get $YD=\sqrt{b^2-x^2}$. $DA=a-b-x$, so $DX=\sqrt{a^2-(a-b-x)^2}$. $$XY=\sqrt{b^2-x^2}+\sqrt{a^2-(a-b-x)^2}$$
$$\frac{d\, XY}{d\,x}=\frac{-x}{\sqrt{b^2-x^2}}+\frac{a-b-x}{\sqrt{a^2-(a-b-x)^2}}=0$$
You can rewrite this last equation as
$$\frac{DB}{YD}=\frac{AD}{XD}$$
This implies that the triangles $BDY$ and $ADX$ are similar, and therefore $YB||AX$.

Comment: Ideally I would have a geometrical proof, because the statement is pretty nice, but +1 anyway